# Expected A Declaration CPP

Tags: c++

little problem and I can't get to the bottom of it. The { at line 35 expected a declaration. I can't for the life of me fix it. Here's all of the code together, I have commented in the code next to the { for where the problem is arising.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char ScoreMarks(float percentage);
char ScoreRawMarks(float scoreAwarded, float mscoreAvailable);

int main(void)
{
    float percent, Awarded, Available;
    char result;
    printf("Enter Score Available\n");
    scanf("%f", &Available);
    printf("Enter Score Awarded\n");
    scanf("%f", Awarded);
    result = ScoreFromRawMarks(Awarded, Available);
    printf("Score Achieved = %c\n", result);
}
char ScoreFromPercentage(float percentage)
{
    char output;
    if (percentage >= 90.0) {
        output = 'A';
    }
    else if (percentage >= 70.0) {
        output = 'B';
    }
    else if (percentage >= 50.0) {
        output = 'c';
    }
    else if (percentage >= 30.0) {
        output = 'D';
    }
    else {
        output = 'F';
    }
    return output;
};
char ScoreFromRawMarks(float scoreAwarded, float scoreAvailable, float percentage);
{ //EXPECTED DECLARATION
    char output;
    percentage = (scoreAwarded / scoreAvailable) * 100;
    output = ScoreFromPercentage(scoreAwarded, scoreAvailable);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Is this really `c++`? It looks like `c` to me.

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of the previous line.

Comment: Obviously, you did "Copy-Paste" of the declaration for the implementation and forgot to remove the trailing semicolon ... While we aren't saints of "Don't do Copy-Paste" ...It can, has, and will hurt badly... trust me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end of this line which makes the compiler think you're doing a function prototype:

```
char ScoreFromRawMarks(float scoreAwarded, float scoreAvailable, float percentage);
{ //EXPECTED DECLARATION
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon from the previous line?

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the error is that Function you written had a semi colon like other people have indicated and was expecting a line to execute. Expected Declaration Errors have to deal with Semi colons and brackets so always check those.